# Prove by Induction on Inequalities

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation, induction

I am given this example in a lecture slide, as shown below, for the proposition:

For every integer $n≥3, 2n+1 <2^n$

[image: Slide given]

In the second step of this proof we get

\begin{align}
       \ P(k+1) &= \ 2(k+1)+1 \\\\
     \ &= \ 2k+1+2 \\\\
     \ &< \ 2^k+2       \        (Since P(k) : 2k+1 < 2^k)  \\\\
     \ &< \ 2^k + 2^k   \        (Since  \ 2^1 < 2^k for \ k≥3)  \\\\
     \ &= \ 2.2^k \\\\
     \ &= \ 2^k+1
     \end{align}

I don't understand these steps here. Why is $2^k$ subbed in for $2k+1$ in line 3? Why, in line 4 does 2 become $2^k$? And why do we change to an inequality on line 3, and then back again in line 5?

Comment: Because in a proof by “induction”, after the base case, you “assume” it holds the the “$k$th” step —that is, $2k+1 <2^k$— as clearly indicated by you in the comment in the brackets); as for the fourth line, it’s to make it easy to demonstrate the conclusion in the next line....the last line, however, is an error; it ought to be $2^{k+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

You are *assuming* that $2k+1<2^k$. Therefore $2k+1+2<2^k+2$.

You are also assuming that $k\geqslant3$. So, $2^k>2$ and it follows from this that $2^k+2<2^k+2^k$.

Finally, we use an inequality when what we have is an inequality and we use an equality when what we have is an equality.

Answer (score 1):

By assuming $2k+1<2^k$

$(2k+1)+2<2^k+2$

and $2<2^k$, for $k>1$

then

$(2k+1)+2<2^k+2<2^k+2^k$

Since after line $4$ it is just addition then they are equal.

But after line $2$ using assumption that is substituting something bigger than previous one.